# Why does an overloaded function in VB.Net need to be Public

Tags: wpf, vb.net, overloading

I take different actions on a Click event depending on where the Click originated, it can be a user control I created (Type MenuControl) or a default Button.

```
Private Sub UpdateStatusImage(ByVal myMenuControl As MenuControl)
Private Sub UpdateStatusImage(ByVal myButton as Button)
```

I call it from another function in the same source file:
     UpdateStatusImage(e.Source)

This fails at runtime with a MissingMemberException - 
    "Public member 'UpdateStatusImage' on type 'FourGLMenu' not found".

FourGLMenu is the name of the class, in this case a WPF page that contains the objects. If I make the Subs Public then it works as expected.
Another point, when I only had the first Sub as Private that worked, it only started failing when I added the overload.

Comment: When you say it works when the first one was private, did it work for both the button click and the menu selection?  If you make the first one public and the second one private does it still work?

Comment: It doesn't.  Sounds like a temporary case of DLL Hell.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear. When I only had one Sub in place

Comment: Hit Enter too soon on that last one, here's the full response:
Sorry I didn't make that clearer. When I only had one Private Sub UpdateStatusImage in place  that took a parameter of type MenuControl it worked. I then added a button to the Page and added another Private Sub UpdateStatusImage that took a parameter of type Button. I then started getting the error until I marked both Subs as Public.